# Как, используя JS + React + Jest + Puppeteer определить, что кнопки с известным селектором НЕТ на странице

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest, puppeteer

Такая вот проблема - я знаю как кликнуть на кнопку с помощью Puppeteer:

```
await expect(page).toClick(deleteButtonSelector);
```

Но не знаю как определить, что кнопки нет на странице (после удаления всех айтемов кнопок с таким адресом должно не остаться, такой ожидаемый результат).
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Нашла решение:

```
await expect(() => page.toClick(deleteButtonSelector)).toThrow();
```